# Polymer data binding with paper elements and local storage

Tags: html, polymer

I want to use some of the Polymer paper elements to present a settings page which stores configuration data in local storage (eventually this will go into a Chrome extension). This looks like it should be easy.

From my understanding of [this Polymer Data Binding article](https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/communication.html#binding), I should just be able to create a data binding like this:

**options.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Options</title>

    <!-- Polymer -->
    <script src="../bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toggle-button/paper-toggle-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-localstorage/core-localstorage.html">

</head>
<body>

    <paper-toggle-button checked="{{bar}}"></paper-toggle-button>
    <core-localstorage name="foo" value="{{bar}}"></core-localstorage>

</body>
</html>
```

But the `foo` value is not being stored in local storage, when I inspect it with the Chrome dev tools, and the toggle-button's checked status is not remembered between page loads.

If I'm reading the [paper-toggle-button documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-toggle-button) correctly, I think that the checked attribute is published, so I should be able to bind it.

I can confirm that no errors are logged in the console and both the `paper-toggle-button` and `core-localstorage` elements are present in the `../bower_components/` folder. The `paper-toggle-button` does appear in the page and animates when clicked, which makes me think that the elements are loaded and running.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't see what it is, and I've never used Polymer before, so I don't know any better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not bind to siblings. You can wrap these two elements by an [auto-binding template element](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#autobinding) or by a custom element and bind `checked` and `value` to a field of the model of the common parent (auto-binding template or the custom element).